# Tossing 10 coins on square table

Tags: probability

Say we have a table divided into equal squares of length $L$ and $n$ coins of diameter $d<L$. What's the probability that all $n$ coins end up inside some squares after tossing them ? I see that on this site we're supposed to describe our attempts, so here's what I got so far :

The probability that a single coin goes inside a square is $\
{\mathop{\rm P}\nolimits}  = \frac{{(L - d)^2 }}{{L^2 }}
$ . But I can't get my head around the whole case...

What would be the probability that all of them end up inside a square ?
(For particular values such as $L=2$, $n=10$,$d=1$)

Comment: The event that a particular coin ending up in a square is independent of any other coin ending up in a square. Thus the probability that all of them end up inside a square should be $P^n$.

Comment: I like this question. heh

Comment: I don't agree with Bruce Zheng that there is independence because a coin already in a square and a coin that is tossed may bump each other thus changing the conditions compared to if no coin was already in that same square. Also what if multiple coins are already in that square? Is it then more likely that another coin will be rejected from that square because it is becoming more full?

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on several additional factors not specified in your original question such as the thickness of the square walls.  For example, a square can have sides of length $2$ inches but how much of those $2$ inches is considered inside the squares?  If they are drawn with a thick magic marker for example, only maybe $1.5$ to $1.75$ inches of them may be considered inside.  You didn't define what you mean by inside the square and you didn't specify what happens if the coin overlaps the square's edge (or edges).

You also didn't specify how the coins are tossed.  What if they miss the table completely?  How would we know what the chances of that happening are?   You didn't specify if that could happen or not.  Also you didn't specify if the coins are all the same size or not.  You stated diameter d < L but each coin could have a different d such as dimes, nickels, pennies...